# How to choose m random numbers from a range but with no duplicate?

Tags: python

For example, I need to choose three numbers from `[-2,2]` but with no duplicate, the following code can't accomplish this, I know I can do it by comparing the elements, but is there some elegant way to do so?

```
print(np.random.randint(-2,2,3))
```

Most general case is: choose `m` random numbers from range`[a,b]` with no duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in random [sample](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(10), 5) # take 5 random elements from range(10)
[2, 4, 1, 7, 9]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want.